# Problem with displaying webpage content in WebView on Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, url, android-jetpack-compose, android-webview

I have a problem showing a page on Webview. When I pass url from Habr it is shown fine but if I pass url from techcrunch.com it shows less then a half of the screen.
URL:
https://techcrunch.com/2024/02/21/loora-wants-to-leverage-ai-to-teach-english/

Code for webview:

```
@Composable
fun WebViewScreen(url: String?) {
    Log.d("MyUrl", url.toString())
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Column {
            AndroidView(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                factory = {
                    WebView(it).apply {

                        webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                                view: WebView?,
                                request: WebResourceRequest?
                            ): Boolean {
                                return false
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, update = {
                    it.loadUrl(url.toString().drop(6))
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I think there is something on techcrunch website that doesn't allow Webview to display content properly but not sure what exactly. Could you please help me?

[image]
[image]